# You don't have permission to access that port

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

In my Django, when I try to run the server, it displays this error.
What should be done to fix the error?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXERG.png)

What should be done to fix the error?[

Answer (score 0):

You need admin rights try this:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```